# Controlar acesso a documentos

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estou criando uma aplicação para gerenciar arquivos, os arquivos estão sendo salvos em um diretório local "localhost/uploads...", tenho uma tabela "documentos" com um campo "urldoarquivo", onde salvo o caminho do arquivo, tambem tenho minha tabela de usuários, agora preciso definir qual usuário pode visualizar/baixar/listar um determinado documento...

Ex: formulario.doc - pode ser visualizado pelo usuário CARLOS, MARCOS e LUCAS...

Se alguém souber como eu posso fazer isso, estou usando codeigniter, não faço a menor ideia de como fazer isso, estou desesperado.

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: **Dica:** Só fazer isso mediante software não garante que os usuários que não tenham permissão a um determinado arquivo possa manipular. Exemplo se ele souber o endereço ele pode baixar o arquivo mesmo não tendo autorização. A idéia acredito ai ser outra.

Comment: então @VirgilioNovic eu tenho a URL do download mas ele sempre está em diretório diferente, exemplo download/jdnfdfad/arquivo.doc, ele manda para a pagina download o caminho que quer baixar, assim o usuario nunca sabe onde o documento realmente está, porque ele criar um nome para cada caminho com 8 digitos....

Comment: @LuanAmado veja os links indicados no fechamento. Quase todas as soluções dadas permitem inclusive que você ponha o arquivo fora do diretório do site, para não recorrer a essa idéia de tentar ocultar o caminho (o que facilmente é quebrado com força bruta, tentando combinações de caracteres). O "segredo" (que não é segredo nenhum) é que o arquivo nunca seja acessível pelo servidor web, e tenha obrigatoriamente que ser intermediado pelo PHP. Usando x-sendfile, que é uma das soluções propostas, você inclusive evita sobrecarga nos scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@luan-amado o que você pode fazer é primeiro criar uma tabela de vinculo entre o usuário e o documento.

Exemplo de Tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE `viculo` (
`id_vinculo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_documento` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_vinculo`)
);
```

E depois no "controler" do Codeigniter na função que você utiliza para tratar o download, antes que realizar o download, você carrega um "model" que vai ter acesso a tabela "vinculo", e chame um função no "model" que verifique se o usuário tem vinculo com este documento, essa função de retornar TRUE ou FALSE.

Exemplo de Model

```
class Viculo_Model extends CI_Model{
    var $table = 'vinculo';
    public function verificar_vinculo($documento,$usuario){
        $this->db->where('id_documento =', $documento);
        $this->db->where('usuario =', $documento);
        $this->db->get($this->table);
        $query = $this->db->get('usuarios');
        $vinculo = $query->row(0);
        if(!$usuario) return false;         
        return true;            
    }
}
```

Se TRUE continua com o download, se FALSE redireciona o usuário para uma "view" informando ao usuário que ele não tem permissão para realizar o download.

Exemplo Controler

```
$this->load->model('vinculo_model');
$vinculo = $this->vinculo_model->verificar_vinculo($documento,$usuario);
if ($vinculo) {
    // coloque aqui o a função de realiza o download
} else {
    // carrega view informando que o usuário não tem permissão
    $this->load->view('sem_permisao', $data);
}
```